# $ \arctan \frac{1}{x}$ uniformly continuous in $(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$

Tags: uniform-continuity

I have to decide if the function $\arctan  \frac{1}{x}$ is uniformly continuous in $(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$.

The function is defined and continuous in $(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$ and it can be extended to $x=1$ putting $f(x=1) =\frac{\pi}{4}$ and to $x=-1$ putting $f(x=-1) =-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Unfortunately there's no way to eliminate the discontinuity in $x=0$ because $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} f(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

So I can't find and extention of the function continuous in a compact interval to apply Weierstrass and then the theorem of extention.

Can someone help me to understand how to solve the problem?

Comment: There is no discontinuity at $0$. The function $x \mapsto x\arctan(x)$ is defined and continuous on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: i beg your pardon I edited the text

Comment: Anne, do you know the theorem of extension of uniformly continuous applications ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't apply it in x=0

Comment: Yes you can. If the function was uniformly continuous, you could extend it to $(-1,1)$ to a continuous function. Do you think this is possible ?

Comment: I wrote a more elementary answer, if you prefer not using a strong tool as extension of uniformly continuous functions.

Comment: I don't understand how can I make this function continuous in x=0 if the discontinuity is not eliminable

Comment: The point is precisely that you *cannot*, and this precisely shows that the funtion *is not* uniformly continuous :)

Comment: ok now I see your answer , you proved it also with the definition

Comment: in your opinion can this problem be solved with the extension theorem or I am kept to solve it with the definition?

Comment: Both work, but in my opinion, it is clearer if you solve it with the definition. One should always try to give the more elementary answer, that is the one which needs the less theory as possible. But if you prefer using the theorem, then use it : it is also correct !

Comment: thanks for your explanation!

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that for all $x \in (0,1)$, you have $$f(x) \geq \frac{\pi}{4}$$

and that for all $y \in (-1,0)$, you have $$f(y) \leq -\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Hence, for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $y \in (-1,0)$, you have
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \geq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

In particular, you have
$$\left|f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| \geq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Can you conclude ?